# RDP Connection to Civicrm VM on Azure failing

Tags: azure, port, endpoint, civicrm

I used the Bitnami image VHD from VM Depo to create an Azure VM running CiviCRM from the ready to go

I added the remote desktop as an end point and when I try to rdp in I get the following error: "This computer can't connect to the remote computer"

These are my settings, any ideas what I need to do to access the VM and get CivicCRM to run ?

Azure VM CiviCRM dashboard: http://cropme.ru/ac4a84a2b5f91640ad843c08da97d80c

Azure VM CiviCRM endpoints: http://cropme.ru/8fc7843477b9652a4029b571690da679

Answer (score 0, accepted):

civiCRM is on Ubuntu Machine! This is a Linux and does not have Remote Desktop enabled by default.

What you have added is an RDP endpoint (standard) for a Windows Server machine. It will not work with Linux images. With any linux images.

If you want to login remotely, your only chance is the SSH via port 22. Once logged-in on the console, you may install some X-Window and enable remoting on it. You will, however most probably need a VNC client for it and not the standard windows Remote Desktop Client.

You also most probably don't need a Remote Desktop at all. CiviCRM is a web-based open source CRM solution. Being web based, means that you have to access it over WEB.

Add a new endpoint - public port 80 and private port 80 for your VM. Then navigate to it with the browser! And you shall see the welcome screen of CiviCRM.

Comment: Generally correct.  RDP and VNC are both possible, but most likely neither is advisable.  You'll also want a file transfer client of some sort.  WinSCP is old, but works fine for me.  Some sort of rsync client might also be useful.  If you're going to try developing locally, I'd recommend not using windows.  Much easier if your local environment is Linux or Mac (Mac being unix-ish under the hood).